# Dynamically Add/Remove html element array structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `jQuery` and `JavaScript` to add/remove `HTML` Element. in that case i remove specific html element

**following code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $("#plus").click(function() {
    i++;
    $('#editrow').append("+<tr id=rownum_" + i + "><td>" + i + "</td>" +
      "<td><input type='text' id='cid_" + i + "' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>" +
      "<td><input type='text' id='lac_" + i + "' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>" +
      "<td><input type='text' id='mnc_" + i + "' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>" +
      "<td><input type='text' id='mcc_" + i + "' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>" +
      "<td><button type='button' id=" + i + " onClick='delrow(" + i + ")' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm'>-</button></td></tr>");
  });
});

function delrow(num) {
  var element = document.getElementById("rownum_" + num);
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>CID</th>
      <th>LAC</th>
      <th>MNC</th>
      <th>MCC</th>
      <th align="right"><button id="plus" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">+</span></button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="editrow">
    <tr id=rownum_1>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input type='text' id='cid_1' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>
      <td><input type='text' id='lac_1' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>
      <td><input type='text' id='mnc_1' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>
      <td><input type='text' id='mcc_1' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>
      <td><button type='button' id=1 onClick='delrow(1)' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm'>-</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Using this code i add element like index 1,2,3,4,5,6 and i remove some element index like 3,4,5 ,and that will deleted.
after we add any element they started with 7,8,9 and show index like 1,2,6,7,8,9
now total element is 6. how to manage that ? , i want to get that index like 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: It's worth mentioning that jQuery is written in JavaScript.

Comment: is this notify the server side that element has deleted or something? what will be happened after page get reload? what is the order server is going to render this?refactoring the dom elements after deleting is the best way I think.just loop the remaining elements & set ID attribute from the 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to handle inserts and updates to the table would be to keep a separate function `resetRowIndex` to assign the row number to every `tr`, without worrying about the index at the time of insertion or deletion. The function `resetRowIndex` can be called after every insert or delete to reset the index of every record.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  resetRowIndex();

  $("#plus").click(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $('#editrow').append("+<tr id=rownum_" + i + "><td>" + i + "</td>" +
      "<td><input type='text' id='cid_" + i + "' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>" +
      "<td><input type='text' id='lac_" + i + "' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>" +
      "<td><input type='text' id='mnc_" + i + "' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>" +
      "<td><input type='text' id='mcc_" + i + "' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>" +
      "<td><button type='button' id=" + i + " onClick='delrow(event)' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign'>Remove</span></button></td></tr>");
      
      resetRowIndex();
  });
});

function delrow(event) {
  var element = $(event.target).closest("tr");
  element.remove();
  
  resetRowIndex();
}

function resetRowIndex() {
  var idx = 0;
  $("#editrow tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("td").first().text($(this).index() + 1);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>CID</th>
      <th>LAC</th>
      <th>MNC</th>
      <th>MCC</th>
      <th align="right"><button id="plus" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign">Add</span></button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="editrow">
    <tr id=rownum_1>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input type='text' id='cid_1' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>
      <td><input type='text' id='lac_1' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>
      <td><input type='text' id='mnc_1' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>
      <td><input type='text' id='mcc_1' class='form-control input-sm' pattern='[0-9]{1-10}' required></td>
      <td><button type='button' id=1 onClick='delrow(event)' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign'>Remove</span></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

<sub>Although this is not the most optimal way of doing so, it is probably the simplest. If you intend to make this optimal, you can write some logic to keep track of the numbers getting deleted, and update subsequent records etc.</sub>

Comment: But sir its not working properly....tested that i add  multiple row, and enter some data, after that i remove that row, it cant be delete....! but another row was delete....

Comment: @mak That should work fine now in the snippet in my answer. I had missed that you are referring to the number while deleting the row. Instead, I have now updated that to refer back to the clicked element using `event.target`, and then you can delete relevant `tr` using: `$(event.target).closest('tr').remove()`.